# Can't make gRPC work with python requests rest api call

Tags: python-requests, grpc, grpc-python

### Need help in wiring the grpc client/server to listen to rest requests. Want to execute a post request

Any help is much appreciated..

*digestor.proto*

```
import "google/api/annotations.proto";
service Digestor{
 rpc GetDigestor(DigestMessage) returns (DigestedMessage) {}
}

service DigestorRest {
  rpc GetDigestor(DigestMessage) returns (DigestedMessage) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get: "/v1/digest"
      body: "*"
    };
  }
}
```

after the pb2 files get generated.

*grpc - request works perfectly ok*

```
curr_client = DigestorClient()
print(curr_client.get_digest("Test Message"))
```

My rest/get request:

```
requests.get(url='http://localhost:46001/v1/digest')
```

should return the correct response however I get

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00\x00\x18\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00 \x00þ\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x04\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00?\x00\x01\x00\x00\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
```

Comment: Are you sure you can pass invalid JSON? `{"Test Message"}` is invalid

Comment: to simplify i modified the proto to a simple get request that returns a sample string. It still throws the same error.

Comment: getting same error, @NovicePythonDev did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using the GCP [Transcoding](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/transcoding) feature. If you haven't tried the tutorial, please try to go through the example steps.

The gRPC protocol is based on HTTP2 instead of HTTP1. The `requests` library is an HTTP1. The exception reported by `requests` looks like protocol mismatch. So, it is likely that there is an issue in your GCP [Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) setting.

Comment: Exactly. You got it right. I am missing something in transcoding that can transcode HTTP1 request to an HTTP2 request and feed into gRPC. However, trying out various alternatives havent worked so far. I am not using GCP, instead i am building on local machine.